# What does rbegin and rend() do in this function?

Tags: c++, function, iterator

What exactly does rbegin() and rend() do in the following function to determine whether input is a palindrome or not?

```
bool palindromeCheck(string input) {
    if (input == string(input.rbegin(), input.rend())) {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Creates a string from the "reverse beginning" to the "reverse end". In other words the string backwards.

Comment: Thank you. Still learning the basics of C++.

Comment: Apparently. But I wanted a clearer explanation, such as below.

Comment: That is not an efficient function because it makes two copies of the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the [constructors for `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) takes a pair of iterators as inputs. [`rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) returns a reverse iterator to the last character of the original `input` string, and [`rend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rend) returns a reverse iterator to the character preceding the first character of the original `input` string (i.e. one past the "end" of the string).

The result is that a new string that is the reversed version of the original is constructed, and if that new string is equal to the original then it's a palindrome and the function returns true.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`rbegin` returns an iterator at the end of the string, `input`. In other words it is a reverse-iterator. `rend` returns an iterator that points *before* the first character in the string.

See: [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rbegin/) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rend/).