# How to understand this C++ palindrome code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, palindrome

I recently came to the solution of the palindrome problem, but I do not understand how this part of code works (with rbegin and rend). Can someone explain it to me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
bool checkPalindrome(string);
int main()
{
    string inputString = "palindrom";
    cout << checkPalindrome(inputString);
return 0;
}

bool checkPalindrome(std::string inputString)
{
   return (inputString == string(inputString.rbegin(), inputString.rend()));
}
```

Comment: It's using the [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) [string constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

Comment: @kuziolewski  This expression  string(inputString.rbegin(), inputString.rend()) creates a string that consists of characters of the original string inputString written in the reverse order.

Comment: Maybe the question is "why does it construct a new string when all that is needed is a reverse iteration?".

Comment: Should not palindrom have option to omits whitespaces?

Comment: @Logman This is simple option of that problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza You mean like `std::equal(inputString.begin(), inputString.end(), inputString.rbegin())` ?

Comment: I think it is funny that I got booted from an interview for doing exactly this (with a trim). Evidently, you are not suppose to whiteboard real code, but only whiteboard the academic version with a manual loop from each end instead.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, exactly (although if C++14 is available, the four iterator version is better.)

Comment: @jaggedSpire Thanks! I was looking for something like that.

Comment: @juanchopanza Maybe ;D

Comment: @kuziolewski  Take into account that it is better to declare the function like bool checkPalindrome( const std::string &inputString);

Comment: Posting tip: we get a lot of people asking for "step by step" tutorials, guides, explanations, and overwhelmingly they are zero-effort questions. The phrase is a bit of a downvote magnet. It is worth noting this (and showing as much of your own work/understanding as you can) so as to get a good reception when you ask. Hope that helps!

Comment: @halfer I'm not sure the phrasing would make much difference. At the very least there are 2 questions here - what is `rbegin` / `rend`, what does `string(iterator, iterator)` do, then there can also be some more basic syntax questions (we have no idea how much knowledge OP has as the question is phrased). It just seems too broad, and any individual part would probably have many duplicates (assuming one can't just find [an exact duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487553/what-does-rbegin-and-rend-do-in-this-function)).

Comment: @Dukeling: I think we're in a fair bit of agreement. I am expressing the view that, on Stack Overflow generally, there is a correlation between requests for "step by step" guides and not having done any research (or at least not having shown any research). I see these quite a lot, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a look at the string constructor:

```
    ...
    (7) template <class InputIterator>
    string  (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

You can see it is possible to create a string via iterators. The rbegin/rend iterators are InputIterators that points to the reverse positions that they refer:

```
    rend() -->"My string"<-- rbegin()
```

That said, when you pass the rbegin() and rend() to the string constructor, it will iterate from the ending, to the beginning of the string, creating the inverted one:

```
    iteration 0: "g"    (currentIterator = rbegin()   : push("g")
    iteration 1: "n"    (currentIterator = rbegin()+1 : push("n")
    iteartion 2: "i"    (currentIterator = rbegin()+2 : push("i")
    ...
    iteration 8: "M"    (currentIterator = rbegin()+8 : push("M")
    iteration 9: rend() (currentIterator = rend()     : stop iteration)
```

Finally, the operator==() will check for equivalence of the strings.

Comment: This explains all my doubts as to how it works, thanks!

Comment: That's a great answer. Really explains how it works at a low level. +1

Answer (score 1):

`string::rbegin` (reverse begin) is iterator to begin of your reverse string (last character of your string), and `string::rend` (reverse end) is the iterator to end of your reverse string (first character of your string).

The string constructor can expect two iterators to create a new string, first one, will be the begin of your string and the second one the end.

When you pass to the constructor the reverse begin and reverse end of `inputString` it is creating a reverse string of `inputString`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're reversing `inputString` and then checking if the two strings are still equal.

`rbegin()` and `rend()` are reverse iterators. There's a string constructor that takes a beginning and ending iterator as parameters.

All `string(inputString.rbegin(), inputString.rend())` does is return the reverse of inputString.